# Allowing users to add SSL verified domains to my kubernetes service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I am currently creating a kubernetes-based service on EKS and using route53 for my DNS. When a new deployment is created (individualized for the client), a subdomain of my service (ie. servername.myservice.com) is created.

This is done relatively easily, and I have an ssl certificate for the my service domain in route53... However, if a client wants to add their own custom domain to the service via a CNAME I am only able to access it via http..... This is because it is still using the cert from MY domain and not theirs (ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).... All traffic is flowing through an ELB that is made on AWS...

In short I would like users to be able to add their own domain somehow while retaining the same https cert from my service domain. I have also tried creating an alias via a route53 hosted zone which I had created for the client's domain.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is a wildcard certificate, which Amazon Certificate Manager will happily issue to you, and then you can bind to the ELB that you described.

You would want to issue the certificate for `*.myservice.com` which will make it valid for `servername.myservice.com` but **will not** make it valid for `www.servername.myservice.com` since the `*` only covers one dns dot level

Comment: The question is about users bringing their own custom domain. This doesn't seem to address that.

Comment: As stated, I have already figured that part out. As Michael stated, I am wondering how to allow users of the service to use their own domains in addition to this.

Comment: No, your question said "a subdomain of my service" and "while retaining the same https cert from my service domain"; nowhere in the question did anyone say "I already have a wildcard certificate". I don't know who this Michael user is, but if they have a better answer, they're welcome to post it. Good luck with your question